# Obtaining value of a np.array based on another np.array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have 2 np.arrays, the first is just an array of values and the second is the rank of those values (in descending order with ties). I am using Python 3.

```
values = np.array([7, 3.5, 3.5, 2, 1])
ranks = np.array([1, 2, 2, 4, 5])
```

So the rank for 7 is 1, rank for 3.5 is 2, rank for 2 is 4, and rank for 1 is 5. The ranks of each value are in the same index or position of the values.

I would like to be able to call on a value and return its respective rank. For example if I called value 3.5, I want it to return rank 2 or if I call value 1, return rank 5. I would also like to keep using NumPy instead of Pandas dataframes. Thank you!

I've seen some thing about Pandas dataframes and using groupby although I am very new to Python and I am still very confused by them so I would like to stick with NumPy if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple subseting:

```
ranks[values == 3.5]
array([2, 2])

ranks[values == 7]
array([1])
```